# How to get child object in embedded Admin class in Sonata Admin?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to get and manipulate the actual object related to a ImageAdmin class in SonataAdmin (using Symfony 2.3). This works fine when the ImageAdmin class is the only one being used. But when ImageAdmin is embedded in another Admin it goes horribly wrong.

Here's what works when you don't have embedded Admins:

```
class ImageAdmin extends Admin {
    protected $baseRoutePattern = 'image';

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $subject = $this->getSubject();
    }
}
```

But when you embed ImageAdmin in ParentAdmin using this:

```
class PageAdmin extends Admin {
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper) {
        $formMapper->add('image1', 'sonata_type_admin');
    }
}
```

Then when you're editing a Parent item with id 10 and call getSubject() in ImageAdmin you get the ***Image*** with id 10!

In other words getSubject() extracts the id from the URL then calls `$this->getModelManager()->find($this->getClass(), $id);`, which cross-references the Parent id and the Image id. Oops!

---

So... what I want to do is be able to get hold of the actual object that is being rendered/edited in the current ImageAdmin instance, whether it's being edited directly or via an embedded form, and then be able to do things with it.

Maybe getSubject() is the wrong tree to be barking up, but I note that `$this->getCurrentChild()` returns false when called from ImageAdmin::configureFormFields(), even when that ImageAdmin is embedded using the sonata_type_admin field type. I'm quite confused...

Anyway, I hope it is possible to get hold of the object in some obvious way that I've overlooked and somebody here can help enlighten me!

Comment: Meanwhile this seams to be fixed, as in my test "$this->getSubject();" return the correct entity in an embedded admin using Symfony 5.4 with sonata-project/admin-bundle 4.x

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to Tautrimas for some ideas, but I managed to figure out an answer to this:

In ImageAdmin set this:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    if($this->hasParentFieldDescription()) { // this Admin is embedded
        $getter = 'get' . $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getFieldName();
        $parent = $this->getParentFieldDescription()->getAdmin()->getSubject();
        if ($parent) {
          $image = $parent->$getter();
        } else {
          $image = null;
        }
    } else { // this Admin is not embedded
        $image = $this->getSubject();
    }

    // You can then do things with the $image, like show a thumbnail in the help:
    $fileFieldOptions = array('required' => false);
    if ($image && ($webPath = $image->getWebPath())) {
        $fileFieldOptions['help'] = '<img src="'.$webPath.'" class="admin-preview" />';
    }

    $formMapper
        ->add('file', 'file', $fileFieldOptions)
    ;
}
```

I'll post this in the upcoming SonataAdmin cookbook soon!

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1546

Comment: caponica's solution is working only on oneToOne relations, am I right? In my oneToMany case , this: $parent->$getter() returns a collection, and I don't know how to identify the current subject. I've found this bug report: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1568, which contains a fix for this, but it is still open, so I hope they merge it soon:(

Answer (score 2):

caponica's solution is working only on oneToOne relations, am I right? In my oneToMany case , this: $parent->$getter() returns a collection, and I don't know how to identify the current subject. 
I've found this bug report: 
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/1568, which contains a fix for this, but it is still open, so I hope they merge it soon:(

**Edit**

With some research there is a temporary fix for this: [Fixed getting wrong subject in sonata_type_collection](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1710)

In short:

create a class and copypaste the content of this file: [AdminType](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/AdminType.php)
then add this to your services.yml, and change the class namespace to you new class namespace:

```
services:
sonata.admin.form.type.admin:
    class: ACME\AdminBundle\Form\Type\AdminType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: sonata_type_admin }
```

It still has a bug though:

> also fix doesn't work when enabled cascade_validation in the parent docment and embedded form has errors

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `$this->getForm()->getViewData();` within your ImageAdmin? This should get you the correct child entity.

Comment: Putting ``$this->getForm()->getViewData()`` inside ``ImageAdmin::configureFormFields()`` seems to cause an infinite loop, an out of memory error and a white screen of death... yikes!

Comment: Then maybe `$formMapper->getFormBuilder()->getForm()->getViewData()` will help?

Comment: Well, that prevents the explosion but ``getViewData()`` returns NULL even though there is a related Image on the Page I'm editing.

Comment: One more thing you could do, is to [listen to form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). This way you could do `$formMapper->getFormBuilder()->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            $subject = $event->getForm()->getViewData();
        });`. Just use appropriate event type that you need. The problem is, that I did not find an easy way to modify Sonata form from event.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! However, I don't think POST_SUBMIT would help... I'm trying to display something on the form *before* the user submits it! However, I'll take a look into it and perhaps PRE_SET_DATA will help.

Comment: Well, I can get the object during POST_SET_DATA but, as you say, I cannot find a way to modify the Sonata Admin form from the event.

Comment: If I were you, I would stop my code in `configureFormFields` using _xdebug_ and search for entity instance manually in `$this` or `$formMapper` variables at various depths. You should really find it somewhere hidden as Sonata is not supposed to be able to add form elements using events.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35139/discussion-between-tautrimas-pajarskas-and-caponica)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all these solutions, but none proved to work.
So, I worked to find a solution. My solution is based on caponica's solution, but work on oneToMany case. Tha solution I found is a workaround, but works good.
It's working using the session.

```
public function getCurrentObjectFromCollection($adminChild)
    {
    $getter = 'get' . $adminChild->getParentFieldDescription()
                               ->getFieldName();
    $parent = $adminChild->getParentFieldDescription()
                   ->getAdmin()
                   ->getSubject();
    $collection = $parent->$getter();

    $session = $adminChild->getRequest()->getSession();
    $number = 0;
    if ($session->get('adminCollection')) {
        $number = $session->get('adminCollection');
        $session->remove('adminCollection');
    }
    else {
        $session->set('adminCollection', 1 - $number);
    }

    return $collection[$number];
}
```

And you get the correct object in the admin by:

```
    $object = $this->getCurrentObjectFromCollection($this)
```

So, when the parent needs to show the list of child admins, each child admin will run this function and will update the session parameter. When all the elements have been taken, the session parameter is deleted.
This code is made for lists with only 2 elements, but can be updated for any number of elements.
Hope this helps somebody :)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and i am able to do this through "Custom Form Type Extension" for which documentation is given on the link "http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html" .

It is the perfect solution ..